# How to import Acclaim's .asf/.mcf motion capture files?

Tags: motion-capture

First of all, I am a total Blender novice!

I need to knowm is it possiple to import Acclaim's motion capture files in Blender? Or rather, how can I do that?

I am especially interested in seeing the skeleton file, I would like to see a drawn skeleton corresponding to the file.

I have found this [link](https://developer.blender.org/T27127) that should provide an extension for this but it seems to be dead.

Any other researches led me to knowhere...

Comment: Maybe you can check if you can convert them to bvh, bvh can be inport to blender

Comment: I can't find any, there was one on the CMU page but the link is dead... http://mocap.cs.cmu.edu/tools.php

Comment: You can Google cgspeed